# Appium - Error This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75, but I do have ChromeDriver 75

Tags: c#, appium, appium-android

I'm learning how to do tests for Ionic app with Appium and C#.

When running a test for Ionic app I get an error:
'''Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. Details: [object Object] session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)'''

Google Chrome browser is installed with version 75.0.3770.90, so Google Chrome and ChromeDriver versions seem to match eachother.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: can you provide the appium server logs from this execution? That should have the actual error about what happened. Might be that the adb installation is old.

Comment: Could You be so kind and tell me how to do that?

I've tired 
driver.Manage().Logs
on try-catch, but in this object there is only AvailableLogTypes property and nothing else.

Comment: yes I actually made a PR about this recently here https://github.com/appium/appium/pull/12781 can you let me know if that helps?